# Converting a string (populated with numbers and white spaces) to int

Tags: c

The goal of this program is to scan a string populated with numbers and white spaces between them and insert each number into an array.

This is the relevent part of my code - im encountering a weird phenomena after trying to scan and print the string supplied by the user .

```
int main()
{
    int exp,size,*numbers,sum=0;
    char term,term2,*str=NULL,*n;


    printf("Enter size of input:");
    if(scanf("%d%c", &size, &term) != 2 || term != '\n'){//checking if a valid size was entered
        printf("Invalid Size\n");
        return 0;
    } if(size<=0){//checking if a valid size was entered
        printf("Invalid size\n");
        return 0;
    } else{//allocating memory to an array and a string with the supplied size
        numbers=(int*)malloc(size * sizeof(int));
        str=(char*)malloc(sizeof(int)*(size+1) + (size-1)*sizeof(char));
        if(numbers==NULL||str==NULL){// in case memory allocation didn't work
            printf("Out of memory\n");
            return 0;
        } else{
            printf("Memory allocated\n");
        }
        printf("Enter numbers:");
        scanf("%s",str);//trying to scan the string
        printf("%s",*str);
        free(numbers);
        free(str);
}
}
```

The moment im done writing an input for the scanf line and press enter the program just ends without printing and i get a warning : 
`warning : forat '%s' expects argument of type ' char *' , but argument 2 has type 'int' ..`

So i went to the `printf("%s",*str);` and changed it to `printf("%d",*str);` but as you might have guessed it spits random numbers.

Comment: Try `printf("%s", str);` instead.

Comment: What are `term` and `term2` for???

Comment: ```printf("%s", str);``` prints the first number (stopped where the first white space is )


ignore the unused variables - they appear later in the code

Comment: changed for fgets . now for example i enter the string ```542 2452 425``` and the output is ```542 2``` ; another example - input : ```312 4356 52``` , output - ```312 435``` . If i had to guess maybe im not allocationg enough space with malloc for the string ?

Comment: Thank you , it is working now

Comment: Use fgets() instead of scanf() to get the string from the user. scantf() doesn't read white spaces.